# How to use data array in tooltipster class?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm looking for a way to show a tooltip when I hover a tr in my table.

```
success: function(data){
   $("table tbody").append('<tr><td>'+data[0]+'</td><tr>');
}
```

The title is the `data[1]` that I retrieving using Ajax Call.

Following the [official documentation](https://www.heteroclito.fr/modules/tooltipster/#getting-started)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster(); //Initializate Plugin

     $('table tr').tooltipster({
     animation: 'fade',
     delay: 200,
     theme: 'tooltipster-default',
     touchDevices: false,
     trigger: 'hover',
     content: $('<span><strong>This text is in bold case !</strong></span>')
  });

};
```

The first test above is working "well", **when I hover the first tr, show me the span and text, hover the second or more, the text disappear but the span keeps there.**

is it possible to use my data array in content tooltip?